# Fortran pointer functions: why does this code's behavior depend on the order of function calls?

Tags: pointers, fortran, gfortran, fortran90

## Context

The toy Fortran code posted below calls two pointer functions.  That is, both functions return a pointer.  In fact, they're both array pointers.  They both attempt to do the same thing, which is to return an integer array pointer referencing an integer array having three elements, 1, 2, and 3.  The first function uses the pointer assignment operator (=>) to point the function pointer to an allocatable array that holds the data.  The second function allocates a block of dynamic memory directly, via the pointer, for storing the data.  The calling program just prints the elements of the returned array(s).

Here's what I find odd.

1. If I point `a` to the result of `function1`, the results are not correct.  The first element of `a` appears to be "clobbered":  `a` has `0`, `2`, `3`.
2. If I point `b` to the result of `function2`, the results are correct.  `b` gets `1`, `2`, `3`.
3. Stranger still, pointing `b` to the result of `function2` ***after*** pointing `a` to `function1` ***changes*** `a` such that it becomes correct.  `a` then has `1`, `2`, `3`.

## Question

Why does this occur?  More precisely, why does a pointer function that returns a pointer to an allocatable array clobber the first element of that array for the caller?  More precisely still, why does pointing one pointer (`b`) produce a side-effect on another pointer (`a`), where the targets come from different functions that are written so as not to interact with each other at all?

## Caveats

I get this behavior using the GNU Fortran compiler v.4.3.3, running an Intel laptop with Ubuntu (Jaunty).  Your results may vary, which might be more interesting still.  Finally, as always it could be operator error on my part, which would be interesting to me at least.

## Code

```
program main
  implicit none
  integer, dimension(:), pointer :: a, b
  integer :: i
  a => function1()
  b => function2()
  do i = 1, 3
     print *, a(i)
  end do
  ! do i = 1, 3
  !    print *, b(i)
  ! end do
contains
  function function1 ()
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable, target :: array
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: function1
    allocate(array(3))
    array(1) = 1
    array(2) = 2
    array(3) = 3
    function1 => array
  end function function1

  function function2 ()
    integer, dimension(:), pointer :: function2
    allocate(function2(3))
    function2(1) = 1
    function2(2) = 2
    function2(3) = 3
  end function function2
end program main
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable *array* of function1 is a local variable -- because it is declared without the "save" attribute, it is not persistent and is undefined when the function exits.  You assign the address of *array* to function1, "keeping" this address, but the address isn't meaningful once the variable becomes undefined after exiting from the function.  A likely implementation is that *array* of function1 will be placed on the stack, and that area of the stack will be freed for other uses when function1 returns.  But this is just a guess at a likely implementation -- the key point is that you aren't allowed to use the pointer value after the variable becomes undefined.  Allocatable variables are automatically deallocated when they go out of scope unless you declare them with the "save" attribute.